GridView not detecting index 1 in if condition
I'm building a grid view where the top right is empty if the itemCount is odd.
Eg.
1 _
2 3
4 5

                 GridView.builder(
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  itemCount: cardList.length % 2 == 0 ? cardList.length : cardList.length + 1,
                  gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                    crossAxisCount: 2,
                    crossAxisSpacing: 8.0,
                    mainAxisSpacing: 8.0,
                  ),
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    if(cardList.length % 2 == 0){
                      return ListTile();
                    } else {
                      cardList.insert(1, DummyContainer());
                      if(index == 1) { return EmptyContainer(); }
                      else { return ListTile(); }
                    }
                  }
                 )

Expected Output:

1 EmptyContainer()
2 3
4 5

Output I'm getting:

1 DummyContainer()
2 3
4 5

Where am I going wrong?

and why do you call cardList.insert(1, DummyContainer()); inside itemBuilder? modify your data model where your data is populated, not inside GridView build callback

@pskink Okay, I'll try that!

How do you get this output?

@pskink It worked. added it to the data model and kept a condition where I want an empty space. Thank you

sure, your welcome

As @pskink mentioned in comments, inserting DummyContainer() to cardList in GridView itemBuilder is where the problem was.
Added isEmpty: true to the model of cardList, and changed the code in this way:
                GridView.builder(
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  itemCount: cardList.length,
                  gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                    crossAxisCount: 2,
                    crossAxisSpacing: 8.0,
                    mainAxisSpacing: 8.0,
                  ),
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    if(cardList[index].isEmpty){
                      return EmptyContainer();
                    } else {
                      return ListTile(); 
                    }
                  }
                 )

